# `ngSubmit` - not working as per expected

Tags: angular

I am using angular5, the form look like :

```
<div class="box-body">
    <form novalidate #formRef="ngForm">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                <label>First name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" ngModel #firstNameRef="ngModel">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                <label>Last name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" ngModel #lastNameRef="ngModel">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formRef.value)">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

The class look like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

interface User {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: "registration-form",
  templateUrl: "./registration-form.component.html"
})

export class RegistrationFormComponent {
  onSubmit(formValue) {
    alert('hi')
    console.log(formValue);
  }
}
```

But when I fill the data in input, and submit nothing consoles. as well the alert not at all called. anything missed here? any one help me

[Live Demo](https://angular-jgldff.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the `(ngSubmit)` event in the `<form>` tag like this (not in the button):

```
<div class="box-body">
    <form novalidate #formRef="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formRef.value)">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                <label>First name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" ngModel #firstNameRef="ngModel">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                <label>Last name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" ngModel #lastNameRef="ngModel">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: the method should not be in `<div class="box-body" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formRef.value)">` which is not works. it should in the `form` tag. works fine

Answer (score 0):

it works for me:

```
<div class="box-body" >
    <form novalidate #formRef="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formRef.value)">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                <label>First name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" ngModel #firstNameRef="ngModel">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                <label>Last name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" ngModel #lastNameRef="ngModel">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```